# httpnotificationchannel same ChannelUri from two different apps in emulator

Tags: c#, push-notification, windows-phone, mpns

I'm new to windows phone development and have started working with push notifications within the emulator in visual studio 2012.  We are having a strange problem where we have two apps in visual studio and when we start each one and call the following:

```
  CurrentChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find("ChannelName");

  if (CurrentChannel == null)
  {
    CurrentChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel("ChannelName");
    CurrentChannel.Open();
    CurrentChannel.BindToShellTile();
    CurrentChannel.BindToShellToast();
  }
```

Even though the `ChannelName` is different in each app the `CurrentChannel.ChannelUri` is the same so when we send push notifications they only go to one app.

I am sure we are missing something very obvious or misunderstanding the way this is supposed to work but any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I supposed you didn't get the right Uri according to your piece of codes. Try to Listen on ChannelUriUpdated event to get a fresh Uri.

If you did, maybe try it on a real device, emulator is not always to be trusted enough.

And Push notification channel URi is unique for device & app combination, to be sure you made something different in these two apps. Anyway seems this couldn't be happened.